# Pandas - Extracting value based of common key

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe in the below format:

```
id, key1, key2
101, {'key': 'key_1001', 'fields': {'type': {'subtask': False}, 'summary': 'Title_1' , 'id': '71150'}}, NaN
101, NaN,{'key': 'key_1002', 'fields': {'type': {'subtask': False}, 'summary': 'Title_2' , 'id': '71151'}}
102, {'key': 'key_2001', 'fields': {'type': {'subtask': False}, 'summary': 'Title_11' , 'id': '71160'}}, NaN
102, NaN,{'key': 'key_2002', 'fields': {'type': {'subtask': False}, 'summary': 'Title_12' , 'id': '71161'}}
```

I am trying to achieve the below output from the above Dataframe.

```
id, key_value_1, key_value_2
101, key_1001, key_1002
102, key_2001, key_2002
```

**Output of df.dict()**

```
{'id': {103: '101', 676: '101'}, 'key1' : {103: {'fields': {'type': {'subtask': False}, 'summary': 'Title_1' , 'id': '71150'},
676: nan}
```

Comment: Can you show us the df.to_dict()?

Comment: @YOBEN_S I have a view of the df.to_dict() to my initial post. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s=df.set_index('id').stack().str.get('key').unstack()
         key1      key2
id                     
101  key_1001  key_1002
102  key_2001  key_2002
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. This however returns back the below output


        'key1  key2
id
101 NaN  NaN`

Comment: for some reason I see the columns are of type `float64` after performing the above code